# Account Billing/Mailing lat and long values are not populated in test data from integration rules

Tags: apex, unit-test, geolocation

I have setup the necessary Account Data Integration Rules for the billing address but in a test context these values are not being populated.

I can't find any documentation on when/how the values get populated or if they're not available in test methods.

I am aware I can set this manually, but does anyone have any supported documentation that delves into this?

Test:

```
@IsTest
public without sharing class AccountsTest {

    @TestSetup
    static void setup() {
        Account a = new Account();
        a.RecordTypeId = [
            SELECT Id
            FROM RecordType
            WHERE SObjectType = 'Account'
                AND DeveloperName = 'Location'
        ].Id;
        a.BillingStreet = '1417 R Street';
        a.BillingCity = 'Sacramento';
        a.BillingState = 'California';
        a.BillingPostalCode = '95811';
        a.BillingGeocodeAccuracy = 'Address';
        a.Name = 'Test Location';
        insert a;
    }

    @IsTest
    static void testLocation() {
        Account a = [SELECT BillingAddress, BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude FROM Account LIMIT 1];

        System.assertNotEquals(null, a.BillingLatitude);
        System.assertNotEquals(null, a.BillingLongitude);

        Location loc = a.BillingAddress;
        System.assertNotEquals(null, loc.getLatitude());
        System.assertNotEquals(null, loc.getLongitude());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that data.com runs asynchronously, and therefore wouldn't be available in a unit test. I can't seem to find documentation on it, but this seems like it couldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not documented, the geocoding uses a third-party provider and happens asynchronously.

You should set the BillingLatitude and BillingLongitude in your test class. Make up whatever numbers you'd like.